# aged away Flag marked old post

Tags: discussion

Today i have noticed, most of pending flags are marked with "aged away".

[image]

There is no details under flagging history:

[image]

Anybody know the details about the aged away flag.. 
When it is introduced and whet it triggered..?
Whether it is auto scheduled or review by some others..?